# Error Configuring Log4Net EventLogAppender

Tags: .net, log4net, event-log, xmlconfigurator

I have a console application using Log4Net 1.2.10.0.  I added an EventLogAppender in my Log4Net config:

```
<apender name="eventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender,log4net" >
    <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <eventLogEntryType value="Error" />
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <eventLogEntryType value="Information" />
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <eventLogEntryType value="Information" />
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <eventLogEntryType value="Warning" />
    </mapping>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</apender>
```

When I call `XmlConfigurator.Configure();` I get the following error:

```
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Configuration update mode [Merge].
log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property [apender] to set object on [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
```

Then later on I get an error stating that the appender "eventLogAppender" does not exist.  Most likely due to the fact that the appender failed during the configuration.

I don't think it's a permissions issue but I tried that anyways and still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appender has two "p"'s in it.  Fix that and you should be good.  Your line is currently

```
<apender name="eventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender,log4net" >
```

and it should be

```
<appender name="eventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender,log4net" >
```

Don't forget to also change your closing line from

```
</apender>
```

to

```
</appender>
```

Comment: I can't believe i missed that.  Thanks!